# Mgento2 curl can't set headers

Tags: header, magento2.3.2

```
/**
 * 创建购物车
 * @param $source
 * @param $token
 * @param string $view
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 * @internal param $data
 */
public function createCart($source, $token, $view = 'default')
{
    $supplier = $this->_help->getSupplier($source);
    $api = $supplier['host'] . "index.php/rest/{$view}/V1/carts/mine";
    $this->_curl->setCredentials($supplier['username'],$supplier['password']);
    $this->_curl->addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    $this->_curl->addHeader('Authorization','Bearer '.$token);
//        $this->_curl->setHeaders(array(
//            'Content-Type'=>'application/json',
//            'Authorization'=>'Bearer '.$token
//        ));
        $this->_curl->post($api, json_encode(array(),true));
        var_dump($this->_curl->getHeaders());die;
        return $this->_curl->getBody();
    }
```

Response :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
$headers = ["Content-Type" => "application/json", "Content-Length" => "200"];
$this->curl->setHeaders($headers);
```

**hope its working for you**

Comment: I have solve it myself !    It wasn't work because I used it for the first time.Think you! You may have noticed my comments，I used your advice. The problem is caused by the token error.

Answer (score 0):

**I have solve it myself !    It wasn't work because I used it for the first time.Think you! You may have noticed my comments，I used your advice. The problem is caused by the token error.the token may be is like this ""token"" so have this error.**